# API in C to mimic a function returning an array

Tags: arrays, c, c11

I am trying to figure out a way to work around the issue with a function returning an array in C (fixed size very short string).

In my case I would need to expose a function to my user which would act **as-if** it was returning:

```
typedef char (bytes2_t)[2];
bytes2_t get_val(struct opaque *opaque);
```

The only solution (I picked union for the implementation, I could have used struct also) I was able to come up with is the following (pseudo-code):

```
typedef union {
  char bytes[2];
  uint16_t val;
} uval_t;
/* intermediate function */
static inline uval_t get_val_impl(struct opaque *opaque) {
  uval_t uval;
  uval.val = 16961; /* opaque->val */
  return uval;
}
/* Actual API */
#define get_val(opaque) get_val_impl(opaque).bytes
```

which works fine in my use-case:

```
struct opaque opaque;
printf("%.2s\n", get_val(&opaque));
```

How would you define an API which would act as-if it was returning a fixed-size short array (2 or 4 chars) without a macro polluting the global namespace ?

Comment: You don't need a union, just a structure. It's okay to return a structure (by value) even if it contains arrays (otherwise you couldn't return a union either actually). Using a union like you do makes the API unusable for use in a C++ program, as only the last-written member of the union could be read from, type-punning with unions is not allowed in C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do not see C++ in the tags..

Comment: @P__J__ I know. But many public libraries with a C API can be (and often are) used by C++ programs as well. My comment was just a remainder that with the current solution as shown in the question, then this can't be used as such. It will be locked to C applications (which might be fine for the time being at least).

Comment: But this isn't an actual opaque type, which means blocking caller access to the structure members by means of incomplete type struct declarations. I'd suggest studying that before anything else.

Comment: @Lundin I am hiding the implementation detail on how I store `val` from the user. The user should only see a `const char*` or `char (bytes2_t)[2]`. This is equivalent to the call `obj_getid` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C)

Comment: No you aren't since the macro `#define get_val(opaque) get_val_impl(opaque).bytes` only works if it has access to the member `bytes`, meaning that caller has it as well. If you were actually hiding the struct implementation the caller wouldn't be able to declare an `struct opaque opaque;` object either.

Comment: `uval_t` != `struct opaque`. In any case, the whole point of my question is precisely on how to improve this.

Comment: But that's a different topic unrelated to returning an array from a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't try to re-invent the C language through macros. That causes unintuitive and confusing APIs. Instead let the caller pass along a buffer as parameter, as done in every other C program out there.

If that for some reason unknown can't be done, the second-most sensible solution is to return a struct, either by value or through a pointer.

Another common but less elegant design is to have a pointer parameter where the allocated storage is passed to the function, then return a pointer to that parameter as well. (Like `strcpy` etc functions do)

And a worst option yet is to return a `malloc`ated hardcopy pointer, as discussed at the bottom of this answer.

---

In this specific case, you haven't actually created an opaque type with private encapsulation, which is why that macro works. Instead you should have something like this:

// opaque.h

```
typedef struct opaque opaque;

opaque* opaque_create (void);

void opaque_free (opaque* obj)

void opaque_get_bytes (const opaque* obj, char bytes[2]);
```

// opaque.c

```
struct opaque
{
   // private members
   char bytes[2];
};

opaque* opaque_create (void)
{
  opaque* obj = malloc (sizeof *obj);
  obj->bytes[0] = 'A';
  obj->bytes[1] = 'B';
  return obj;
}

void opaque_free (opaque* obj)
{
  free(obj);
}

void opaque_get_bytes (const opaque* obj, char bytes[2])
{
  bytes[0] = obj.bytes[0];
  bytes[1] = obj.bytes[1];
}
```

// caller.c

```
#include "opaque.h"

opaque* op = opaque_create();

char buf[2];
opaque_get_bytes(op, buf);
```

If you insist on returning an array through the return value - and it must be a hardcopy, since we shouldn't expose private members through pointers - then you end up responsible for the allocation of those bytes:

```
// bad idea
char* opaque_get_bytes (const opaque* obj)
{
  char* result = malloc (sizeof char[2]);
  result[0] = obj.bytes[0];
  result[1] = obj.bytes[1];
  return result;
}
```

Now we've created an icky API where the caller is responsible for deallocating these bytes. As seen thousand times before in other icky, memory leaking C programs. It's preferable to always leave allocation to the caller. And that's the true reason why we should avoid returning pointers from functions - there are valid special cases, like the opaque type itself - but most of the time it's simply bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

A typical C89 compiler, given a construct like:

```
doSomething(functionReturningStructure().someArray);
```

would typically take the address of a temporary object used to hold the return value, displace it by the offset of the array, and treat that result as the value of the expression `functionReturningStructure().someArray` whereupon it could decide it was done with that temporary structure.  Sometimes this would result in the called function receiving the address of a usable array, and sometimes not.

C99 attempted to firm up the rules to extend the lifetime, but it's not quite clear what the resulting lifetime is supposed to be.  One could read the Standard as requiring that a compiler, given:

```
(f1() ? f2(f3().array) : f4(f5.array())) || f5();
```

would need to ensure that the lifetime of either `f3().array` or `f5().array`--whichever was actually evaluated--must extend through the call to `f5()`, and some compilers might do that, but proper and efficient handling of all the corner cases involving the lifetime of objects that may or may not be created would necessitate a level of compiler complexity far beyond anything the authors of the Standard would likely have intended.

It's possible that all of the currently-maintained compilers that claim to be C99 compatible will correctly handle all of the necessary corner cases correctly, but I would regard such things as constructs which even compilers claiming to be C99 compatible should not be relied upon to process in any particular fashion, even if a reasonably straightforward reading of the Standard would indicate that they must do so.